# Iterating dictionaries to generate twitter sentiments

Tags: python, twitter, data-science

I am doing an Online Course where i am trying to analyse tweets. I want to traverse dictionaries, one with tweets and one with words and corresponding sentiments (love = 3, sadness = -3, etc.). With some help i wrote the following code but it gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/Users/fabiangeiger/Code/datasci_course_materials/assignment1/test.py",
line 22, in <module>
    print traverse_tweets(tweet_file, scores)   File "/Users/fabiangeiger/Code/datasci_course_materials/assignment1/test.py",
line 17, in traverse_tweets
    return [cmp_tweet_sentiment(tweet, scores) for tweet in tweets]   File
"/Users/fabiangeiger/Code/datasci_course_materials/assignment1/test.py",
line 13, in cmp_tweet_sentiment
    return sum(scores.get(word, 0)) TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

The tweet-dictionary contains tweets in following format. The example shows the beginning of a single tweet: `{"created_at":"Wed May 24 15:51:00 +00002017","id":867407593760796672,"id_str":"867407593760796672",‌​"text":"ai, nada estraga meu dia hoje .... etc}`. The sentiment file looks like this, separated by a tabstop: abandon   -2 abandoned    -2 abandons -2 In the end each tweet should have a sentiment score, made up by assigning a score to specific words that are contained in the senimtent-file.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
import json

def read_sentiment(sent_file): # parse the sentiment file and return  a {word: sentiment} dictionary
  scores = {} # initialize an empty dictionary
  for line in sent_file:
    term, score  = line.split("\t")  # The file is tab-delimited. "\t" means "tab character"
    scores[term] = int(score)  # Convert the score to an integer.
  return scores # Print the dictionary itself

def cmp_tweet_sentiment(tweet, scores):
  for word in tweet.split():
    return sum(scores.get(word, 0))

def traverse_tweets(tweet_file, scores): #calculate scores for all tweets
  tweets = (json.loads(line).get("text", '') for line in tweet_file)
  return [cmp_tweet_sentiment(tweet, scores) for tweet in tweets]

sent_file = open("AFINN-111.txt")
tweet_file = open("problem_1_submission.txt")
scores = read_sentiment(sent_file)
print traverse_tweets(tweet_file, scores)
```

Comment: can you add an overview of your input file and what is the expected output ? It will be helpful to understand what you try to do.

Comment: The tweet-dictionary contains tweets in following format. The example shows the beginning of a single tweet:
{"created_at":"Wed May 24 15:51:00 +0000 2017","id":867407593760796672,"id_str":"867407593760796672","text":"ai, nada estraga meu dia hoje .... etc. 

The sentiment file looks like this, separated by a tabstop:
abandon -2
abandoned -2
abandons -2

In the end each tweet should have a sentiment score, made up by assigning a score to specific words that are contained in the senimtent-file.